# How to send an email with snapshot of New Relic chart data

Tags: performance-testing, newrelic, newrelic-platform

We use New Relic and I was tasked with figuring out a way to send an email every morning with the results of our overnight load and performance testing. I need to be able to just send a snapshot of a certain time frame that the test(s) is/are ran, showing things like the throughput, web transaction time, top DB calls, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate dynamic permalinks for any given time window in New Relic by using UNIX time. For example:

```
https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/<your_account_id>/applications/<your_application_id>?tw%5Bend%5D=1501877076&tw%5Bstart%5D=1501875276
```

Adjust the `tw[end]` and `tw[start]` values to the time range you want to return.

Comment: I did find that, created my own custom dashbaord with the charts I need and that permalink.

Any way to make it public and send a report from NR that has that? If not I guess I'll be looking at API calls to get that data.

Comment: You cannot have publicly available dashboards in New Relic, but you can have [publicly available embedded charts](https://blog.newrelic.com/2011/01/28/embed-rpm-charts-anywhere/).

Comment: In insights, I created a dashboard with my charts, I can't find a way to make it publicly available and embedded. Docs from here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/insights/use-insights-ui/export-data/embed-insights-widgets-external-webpages

I hover over any of my charts added on my insights dashboard and don't have the query icon it mentions. maybe its a perms thing, working on that as well.

Comment: You can review all your embeddables at `https://insights.newrelic.com/accounts/your_account_id/manage/embeddables`